# How to get **nested** objects as JSON from Ruby on the backend to AJAX in the front-end

Tags: javascript, json, ruby, ajax, recursion

Note: The question and answers to this post were edited along the way.  If the comments do not make sense, it is because the original question and answers were different.  I think it still has a lot of good info, though.

Update:  I am brand new to Ruby.  After trying some of the solutions recommended on this post, I found that the .to_json method **does** work on nested hashes and arrays. The issue is that it does **not** work on nested hashes and arrays, if they are instances of a class.  I have data that is nested class instances, and when I parse the JSON on the client-side, it gives me this:

```
["#<Cake:0x00007fc37b19f988>", "#<Cake:0x00007fc37b19f5c8>"] 
0 : "#  <Cake:0x00007fc37b19f988>" 
1 : "#<Cake:0x00007fc37b19f5c8>"
```

(It's just strings with object id's)

If anyone can help point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

**Original Question:**

I am using sinatra/Ruby on the backend, and I am using an ajax call on the front-end.

I am not able to parse the JSON object once it gets to the front end.  I saw that the JSON was only parsing one level deep.  In other words, if I have an array of objects, I could get those objects, but I could not get any nested objects;  so, I wrote a recursive function to try to properly format the nested objects, but they still won't parse.

Can anyone help me figure out how to send JSON from Ruby to an AJAX request.

This is my Ruby code:

```
require 'json'

 sample_data = [
    { :category => 'muffin', 
      :flavor => 'chocolate', 
      :ingredients => {
        :dairy => ["milk", "butter"],
        :grain => ["wheat"]
       }
    },
    { :category => 'muffin', 
      :flavor => 'blueberry', 
      :ingredients => {
      :dairy => ["milk", "butter"],
      :grain => ["wheat"]
    }
 }]

#recursive function that applies .to_json to every nested array or object:

def jsonify(data)
  if data.class == Hash
    container = {}
    data.each do |key, value|
      if value.class != Hash && value.class != Array
        container[key.to_sym] = value
      else
        container[key.to_sym] = jsonify(value)
      end
    end
  elsif data.class == Array
    container = []
    index = 0
    while index < data.length
        value = data[index]
        if value.class != Hash && value.class != Array
            container[index] = value
        else
            container[index] = jsonify(value)
        end
        index += 1
    end
  end
  container.to_json
end
```

This is what my route is sending:

```
jsonify(sample_data)
```

Formatted my Ajax request as a promise(but don't think that's relevant?)

```
requestPromise("http://localhost:4567/jsondata","GET")
.then(data => {
 let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(parsedData)

})
.catch(err => {
console.log(err)
})
```

But, on the client-side, I just get this:

(2) ["{"category":"muffin","flavor":"chocolate","ingredi…\"butter\\"]\",\"grain\":\"[\\"wheat\\"]\"}"}", "{"category":"muffin","flavor":"chocolate","ingredi…\"butter\\"]\",\"grain\":\"[\\"wheat\\"]\"}"}"]

All of my nested objects are still strings, and have a bunch of escape characters.

Can anyone please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong, and how to do it correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `parsedData`?

Comment: Why not call `sample_data.to_json`? By attempting to alter the inner objects, you're throwing the JSON module off.

Comment: @fongfan999 The JSON string is being captured by the 'data' variable.  parsedData is the name I gave to the result of passing that string to the JSON.parse() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jsonify` method is hurting you.

You should call `sample_data.to_json` directly and let the JSON module deal with the nesting.

---

**EDIT** (JSON with custom data type):

To support `#to_json` within your custom class / object, you need to add a `#to_json` method to your class. i.e.:

```
require 'json'
class MyClass
   def initialize name, age
     @name = name
     @age = age
   end
   def to_json(*a)
     {name: @name, age: @age}.to_json(*a)
   end
end

[ MyClass.new("John", 24) ].to_json
```

Comment: Wow!  I could swear that that method was not working for two days.  Even my teacher was trying to get it to work, with no avail.  And I just tried it again to make sure; BUT this time it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: would you know off the top of your head, if I would be getting error messages because my original data were class instances?  I'm going to try again and hope that I still don't get errors :)

Comment: @ Myst  I went back to my original data to try it out, and this is what I'm getting:   {cake: Array(2), cupcake: Array(2), muffin: Array(2)}
cake
:
Array(2)
0
:
"#<Cake:0x00007fbc3c994da0>"
1
:
"#<Cake:0x00007fbc3c9d7d80>"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
cupcake
:
Array(2)
0
:
"#<CupCake:0x00007fbc3c9ad3c8>"
1
:
"#<CupCake:0x00007fbc3c9ad1c0>"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
muffin
:
Array(2)
0
:
"#<Muffin:0x00007fbc3c992e60>"
1
:
"#<Muffin:0x00007fbc3c992cd0>"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: All of the instance objects are just strings that look like Ruby hash id's (I don't know the technical term)

Comment: @Maiya - yes, if you're using custom data types Ruby (something other than the Array, Hash, etc'), you will need to have each object implement it's own JSON logic. There's [a blog post about it](https://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/) as well as some other information if you google it.

Comment: @Maiya - I updated the answer to provide some more details.

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out why you have to use the splat parameter *a (or any parameter) in your method. Like I said, I am new to Ruby; so maybe this is something basic that I will have to learn about down the road. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Maiya , [the method `to_json` accepts an optional hash with different options](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-generate). I ignored it in my example, but you might want to use or forward these options to your implementation.